# Will a question get closed if an answer is not chosen as the accepted answer?

Tags: support, closed-questions, unanswered-questions

On Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow, if an answer from the answers given to the question is not selected as the accepted answer, will the question get closed?

Answer (score 7):

No.

If there is no accepted answer, that could mean that none of the existing answers fully answers the question. In this case, blocking new answers by closing or even deleting the question is definitely the last thing you want to do here.

Comment: Ah! delete, delete.... that was the word. So will a question get deleted if I can't mark an answer accepted due to all the questions answer my question?

Comment: @user152435 Same thing with deletion. Although questions with a negative score and no good answer may get deleted at some point.

Comment: Is it "questions with a negative score **and** no good answer"?

Comment: @user152435 my bad, it's *"questions with negative score and no answer"* as [stated here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/164356).

Answer (score 4):

No, closing means there is something wrong with the post. A post that doesn't have an accepted answer isn't wrong, it might a excellent but hard-to-answer question. What would be the point in deleting it?

In some circumstances questions without accepted answer are deleted: there is a script that deleted old, abandoned and negatively scored questions with not-positively scored and unaccepted answers. Those are deemed 'bad quality' questions and they are *deleted*, not *closed*.